# How to disable breadcrumbs?

Tags: android-studio

I searched now for a long time, but I can't find any option to disable the breadcrumbs on the top. I think it's just an easy click but I can't find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can disable it via `View -> Navigation Bar`

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can disabled those in Preferences > Editor > General > Appearance and then uncheck the option "Show Breadcrumbs" and those will disappear.

Comment: @Ruan_Lopes Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

To disable only Breadcrumbs

On Mac

> Android Studio Menu -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Appearance and then uncheck the option "Show Breadcrumbs" and those will disappear

On Linux/Windows

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance and then uncheck the option "Show Breadcrumbs" and those will disappear

Answer (score 0):

**For Android Studio 3.4:**

Mac: Android Studio Menu -> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Breadcrumbs -> uncheck "Show breadcrumbs"